# Configure docker repo with https without domain name

Tags: docker, https, certificate, docker-registry, self-signed

I have a website that I'm running on a digital ocean droplet, which I want to continuously deploy via docker and a Teamcity build server which I have running on my home server.  I want to enable https on my docker repo, with a self signed certificate, and without a domain name.

Let's say my home's ip address is `10.10.10.10` and the docker repo is running on port `5000`.

I followed the steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate), however docker on my website complained that it cannot connect to the docker repo on my homeserver because it doesn't specify an IP in the SAN extension.

Okay.  So I created a new certificate without the CN field and only an IP in the SAN, and now my cert config on my website looks like...

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/10.10.10.10:5000/ca.crt
```

I also added the cert to my general certs (Ubuntu 16.04 btw)

Then I try to pull the image from my home server to my website...

```
docker pull 10.10.10.10:5000/personal_site:latest
```

However, I'm getting this error.

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://10.10.10.10:5000/v1/_ping: x509:
certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: 
invalid signature: parent certificate cannot sign this kind of 
certificate" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "serial:xxx")
```

I thought by adding my cert to the `/etc/docker/...` it would accept a self-signed cert.  Anyone have any advice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't used a self signed certificate for this, it needs to be a CA certificate. Follow the [same steps required to create a certificate for a docker host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) and store your CA in `/etc/docker/certs.d/...`. Or you can also define 10.10.10.10 as an insecure registry as part of the docker daemon startup (`dockerd --insecure-registry 10.10.10.10:5000 ...`) and docker should ignore any certificate issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same thing with this instructions [create private repo with password without domain and ssl](https://github.com/thien0291/install_registry_with_docker_compose_instructions/blob/master/docker_registry_private_repo_deploy_ubuntu_16_04.md). That will require you to add certificate on client and domain on host file (if you love to have an domain yourself without registering new domain)